# cakephp, session not working unless allow a cookie in browser

Tags: session, cakephp, cookies

Using latest version of cakephp v2.3.3

I have a problem with my session variables when a browser doesn't allow cookies.
I pass variables from one controller to the other and this works perfect as long as the browser has cookies enabled. I have tried it with the Session helper in the controllers, but no effort, same problem.

How to fix this, is there a work around???

Comment: There is a security vulnerability in CakePHP v2.3.3. You should upgrade to v2.3.4. It doesn't require any changes to your code, just replace the `libs/cake` directory.

Comment: Thanks updating right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are required to keep track of the session ID, but you can manually get or set the session ID using `$this->Session->id()`. By adding the code below to the App Controllers' before filter you can set the session ID as a URL paramter like  `http://example.com/posts/view/1?session=qkv108c2pqeubcpeos1q7ekds3`, for example.

```php
if (!empty($this->request->query['session'])) {
    $this->Session->id($this->request->query['session']);
}
```

The session ID is required for every request which means you have to include it in every link. I would suggest extending the HTML helpers' url and link methods to automatically add it.

**Edit:**

You should verify that `$this->Session->read('Config.userAgent');` or `$this->request->clientIp();` has not changed since the user was authenticated to prevent session hijacking. Thanks to thaJeztah for pointing this out.

Comment: Just be sure to properly check ip-address and browser-client, to prevent session fixation / hijacking http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14093/why-is-passing-the-session-id-as-url-parameter-insecure

Comment: Thanks for all comments, much appreciated!